# Get Element XPath of Selected Element

Tags: javascript

I want to build a system where user specifies external website url , it loads the webpage and when I select any element of loaded page it should give me xpath of it.

Comment: what do you mean by xpath?

Answer (score -1):

You have to be more specific, when you say you want to have the xpath of an element. In most cases there exist numerous different xpaths, which all point to the same element. For example you may identyfy them by id, name, css-class etc.

Comment: one xpath will denote one element exactly. Its more like path from root node to that element. For more info read http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: @volatile True, but you didn't want to find an element by xpath but the exact opposite. Many xpaths can denote the one element.